# Quick updates in table with Qt UI

Tags: c++, qt

I created a snipped of code that implements a QAbstractTable model and retrieves the values from random generator. What I was aiming was to get approx 60 updates per second(that was the initial expectations, but I can go down to less, as long as CPU utilization is not very high)

This is the code of the tablemodel:

```
#include "tablemodel.h"
#include <QRandomGenerator64>

TableModel::TableModel(QWidget* parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ROWS; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j){
            m_values[i][j] = QRandomGenerator::global()->generate();
        }
    }
}

int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return ROWS;
}

int TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return COLS;
}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
//       return QString("%1").arg(m_values[index.row()][index.column()]);
        return QString("%1").arg(QRandomGenerator::global()->generate());
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void TableModel::update()
{
    emit dataChanged(index(0,0), index(ROWS-1,COLS-1));
}
```

and this is the code of the table view owner:

```
TableHolder::TableHolder(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::OptionChain),
      m_table_model(parent),
      m_timer(this)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(7);
    ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(7);
    ui->tableView->setModel(&m_table_model);
    connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &TableHolder::refresh);
    m_timer.start(16);
}

TableHolder::~TableHolder()
{
    m_timer.stop();
    delete ui;
}

void TableHolder::refresh()
{
    m_table_model.update();
}
```

But when I run the example in Windows 10, the table slows down to less than one update per second, when the table size is 44x36. I know it's 1.5k cells, but I am surprised how bad is the performance.

I do need sorting, column interactions etc, therefore drawing from scratch does not seem to be a good idea...
Also, tried QTreeView, with the same model, but similar performance...

Any ideas how to make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a profiler to find out what part of the code is actually slow.

[GammaRay](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/gammaray/) from KDAB is a Qt specific profiler.